# How do I store data in an Angular Material DatePicker element?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use material-angular for Angular8. And here, when I click on a date in DatePicker, I want it to filter what happened on that date among my records. How can I do it?

**1. HTML ADD FILE**

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of birth" formControlName="dob"
        (dateChange)="formatDate($event)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      <mat-error *ngIf="handleError('dob', 'required')">
        Date of birth is required
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**2. TS LIST FILE**

```
import { Student } from './../../shared/student';
import { ApiService } from './../../shared/api.service';
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
selector: 'app-students-list',
templateUrl: './students-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./students-list.component.css']
})

   export class StudentsListComponent implements OnInit {
   StudentData: any = [];
   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Student>;
   @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: 
   MatPaginator;
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['_id', 'student_name', 
  'student_email', 'section', 'test', 'action'];

  constructor(private studentApi: ApiService) {
     this.studentApi.GetStudents().subscribe(data => {
     this.StudentData = data;
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Student>. 
     (this.StudentData);
     setTimeout(() => {
         this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     }, 0);
  })    
  }


  ngOnInit() { }

  deleteStudent(index: number, e){
  if(window.confirm('Emin misiniz?')) {
  const data = this.dataSource.data;
  data.splice((this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize) + 
  index, 1);
  this.dataSource.data = data;
  this.studentApi.DeleteStudent(e._id).subscribe()
   }
   }


    }
```

So I don't know how I can do it. I'll be happy if you can help me.

Comment: please add the code that related to the components comonication. Basicly you need to listen on the 'dob' form control and do what ever you want with it.

Comment: First, I don't see that you have any formGroup defined, if you want to use this format I recommend [formControl] without formGroup only in ts add dob = new FormControl(''), and next depend how you get data

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you have a directive (dateChange)="formatDate($event)" which holds the key

So in your ts file you will have the implementation of the function formatDate which will have the current selection and you can use can to filter your data.

If you are still struggling make a stackbliz i will be happy to update it. best.